# bootstrap nav dropdown this.hash undefined

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm working on creating my nav dropdown. It's working. However I'm getting the following error whenever the dropdown is clicked.

```
TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined

$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 5 }, 1000);
```

Here is my html.

```
<div class="main-nav">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                        <h1>
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></h1>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="scroll active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">

                            <a  href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Service<span class="caret"></span></a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#services">Asset Management</a></li>
                                <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
                                <li><a href="/Service">Asset Management</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Service">Consulting</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Service">Due Diligence</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Service">HOA Account Management</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Service">Loan Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Service">Property Maintenance and Inspections</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Service">Property Management</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Service">Real Estate Brokerage</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Service">Tax Account Management</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Service">Utility Account Management</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="scroll"><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>                             

                        <li class="scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here in my main.js I have the code that handles the opening and closing.

```
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').on('click', function () {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 5 }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

I'm trying to figure out why it's giving this error and I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the jQuery selector

```
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').on('click', function () {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 5 }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

will select any anchor `a` inside any `li` inside any `ul` but if you look closely at the markup you notice that it will grab the `dropdown-toggle` anchor:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="scroll active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a  href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Service<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <!-- There is a nested ul that you need to get to -->
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#services">Asset Management</a></li>
                <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
                <li><a href="/Service">Asset Management</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Service">Consulting</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Service">Due Diligence</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Service">HOA Account Management</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Service">Loan Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Service">Property Maintenance and Inspections</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Service">Property Management</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Service">Real Estate Brokerage</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Service">Tax Account Management</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Service">Utility Account Management</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="scroll"><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>                             

          <li class="scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Change your selector to

```
$('.navbar-collapse ul ul li a').on('click', function () {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 5 }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

Hope it helps.